# Field name `email` is not valid for model `customer`. in Multi User authentication Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to create a multiple user authentication system in Django and am using onetoone field and booleans for creating profiles. But when creating serializers it throws the error:

> "Field name `email` is not valid for model `customer`."

Can someone please clarify what am I doing wrong here?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager

# Create your models here.
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The email must be set")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("The password must be set")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


class user(AbstractBaseUser):
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_restaurant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = UserManager

class customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(user,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class restaurant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(user,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rest_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class userserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = user
        fields = '__all__'

class cust_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = customer
        user = userserializer(read_only=False)
        email = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=False,source = 'user.email')
        password = serializers.StringRelatedField(source = 'user.password')
        fields =   [
            'id',
            'email',
            'password',
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
        ]
    
    def create(self,validated_data):
        user1 = user.objects.create(self,email=validated_data['email'],password=validated_data['password'])
        user1.is_customer = True
        user1.save()

        instance = customer.objects.create(user=user1,firstname = validated_data['firstname'],lastname = ['lastname'])
        return user1


class rest_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = customer
        fields = [
            'id',
           # 'email',
            #'password',
            'rest_name',
        ]

    def create(self,validated_data):
        user = super().save()
        user.is_restaurant = True
        user.save()
        instance = customer.objects.create(user=user,rest_name=validated_data['rest_name'])
        return instance
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import customer,restaurant,user
from .serializers import cust_serializer,rest_serializer
from rest_framework import generics 
from rest_framework.response import Response

class createcustomer(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = cust_serializer
    queryset = user.objects.filter(is_customer = True).values()
    
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        cust = cust_serializer(data=request.data)
        if cust.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            cust.save()
            return Response(cust.data)
```

have tried different methods like stringrelatedfield shown above but no progress.
using `fields = ('__all__')` I get user as one of the fields in the post request.